# How to evaluate the trust-constr Lagrangian?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm using the `trust-constr` algorithm from `scipy.optimize.minimize` with an interval constraint (lowerbound < g(x) < upperbound).
I would like to plot the Lagrangian in a region around the found solution to analyze the convergence behavior.

According to my knowledge, the Lagrangian is defined as:

[image: formula]

with:

[image: formula]

In the returned `OptimizeResult` object, I can find the barrier parameter, but the slack variables are missing.  The Lagrange multipliers are present, but there is only one per interval constraint, while I would expect two since each interval constraint is converted to two canonical inequality constraints:

[image: formula]

Clearly, I'm missing something, so any help would be appreciated.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import scipy.optimize as so
import numpy as np

# Problem definition:
# Five 2D points are given, with equally spaced x coordinates.
# The y coordinate of the first point is zero, while the last point has value 10.
# The goal is to find the smallest y coordinate of the other points, given the
# difference between the y coordinates of two consecutive points has to lie within the
# interval [-3, 3].

xs = np.linspace(0, 4, 5)
y0s = np.zeros(xs.shape)
y0s[-1] = 10

objective_fun = lambda y: np.mean(y**2)

def constraint_fun(ys):
    '''
    Calculates the signed squared consecutive differences of the input vector, augmented
    with the first and last element of y0s.
    '''
    full_ys = y0s.copy()
    full_ys[1:-1] = ys
    consecutive_differences = full_ys[1:] - full_ys[:-1]
    return np.sign(consecutive_differences) * consecutive_differences**2

constraint = so.NonlinearConstraint(fun=constraint_fun, lb=-3**2, ub=3**2)

result = so.minimize(method='trust-constr', fun=objective_fun, constraints=[constraint], x0=y0s[1:-1])

# The number of interval constraints is equal to the size of the output vector of the constraint function.
print(f'Nr. of interval constraints: {len(constraint_fun(y0s[1:-1]))}')

# Expected nr of Lagrange multipliers: 2x number of interval constraints.
print(f'Nr. of Lagrange multipliers: {len(result.v[0])}')
```

Output:

```
Nr. of interval constraints: 4
Nr. of Lagrange multipliers: 4
```

Expected output:

```
Nr. of interval constraints: 4
Nr. of Lagrange multipliers: 8
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example where you think there are missing lagrangian multipliers? Note also that you can easily compute the slack variables s on your own because g(x) + s = 0.

Comment: @joni I've added the example.  g(x) + s = 0 is the equality constraint originating from the inequality constraint g(x) < 0, but doesn't that mean that the algorithm will try to satisfy that equality constraint, not that it is necessarily exactly true (especially when not converged, but even at convergence)?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there should indeed be 8 lagrangian multipliers. As a workaround, you can use the old dictionary constraints instead of the `NonlinearConstraint` objects.

```py
lb, ub = -3**2, 3**2
# Note that lb <= g(x) <= ub is equivalent to g(x) - lb >= 0, ub - g(x) >= 0
cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda ys: constraint_fun(ys) - lb},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda ys: ub - constraint_fun(ys)}]

res = minimize(objective_fun, method="trust-constr", x0=y0s[1:-1], constraints=cons)
```

Here, 'fun' is expected to be a function such that fun(x) >= 0. This gives me 8 lagrangian multipliers as expected. Nonetheless, it should also work with `NonlinearConstraint`s, so it might be worth opening an issue at the scipy repo on Github.

Regarding your second question: `res.constr` contains a list of the constraint values at the solution, i.e. the values of `g(x) - lb` and `ub - g(x)`. Since we have `g(x) - lb - s = 0` and `ub-g(x)-s=0` it follows immediately that `res.constr` are just the values of the slack variables you are looking for (when we use dictionary constraints).